# Stop scrolling in back div

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css

I am writing a web-app for iPhone and Android using HTML5 and CSS3.

I have a background div and a menu div on top of it. (larger z-index) and both div's have overflow and are scrollable.

The problem is, even when I swipe my finger over the top div (the menu) the bottom div (the background) is still scrolling. Sometimes both are scrolling at the same time and sometimes only one of them.

I wish only for the menu to scroll when I am swiping the finger over the menu area.

Can anyone help?

Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div id="main">

         <div id="menu">

           <!-- menu content goes here -->

         </div>

      </div>
   </body>   
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#main: {
   height: 3000px;
   overflow: scroll;
}

#menu: {
   height: 2500px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: how could we help you?

Comment: please put ur code on here

Comment: tell me how to disable the scrolling of the background div, please?

(it's a HUGE project... code is way to big.  I will try to make a small example)

Comment: see my solution, if it does not work... try setting the overflow to hidden

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar. Your question is a bit unclear... But I had to make a scrollable div that was not visible... Here is my css...

```
#sidebar{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 670px;
    border: 0px solid transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0.5%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}

#sidebar #scroller{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 545px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: scroll; 
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

and now in my html...

```
   <div id="sidebar">
      div id="scroller">
          // the things i add in my scrollable menu...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can also add background class behind these classes like i did, in order to make mine look like an ios scroll list or whatever you call it

Comment: Thank you very much, first. This is somewhat like what i did. The problem is - i have a big main div behind the sidebar menu. and it is also scrolling when i scroll the side bar... i don't want that to happen. when i scroll the sidebar - i want the background to stay put.

Comment: So I thought. I did the same thing for a blackberry device... ulg... Did the code help you/work ?

Comment: if that div is scrollalbe(the big main div), you need to make sure it cannot scroll. Set overflow to hidden. usually works. otherwise, let us know

Comment: the sidebar is comming in and out of the screen at need. so i do need the main div to be scrollble *when the menu is closed*...

Comment: mmm... doing it with just css is going to be impossible... you will need to use javascript. what you can do is hook code into your javascript function that sets the main div to scrollalbe when the menu is closed, and set it to not scrollable when the menu is open. you will need to do something like this. as doing it in css is not going to work. #menu is a child of #main and thus will always be of a lower z-index. meaning the main will always scroll as long as it is set to scrollable.

Comment: thanks again, and sorry for being difficult about this.
it's a huge project and i am using many javaScript files, so it's no problem :) Yet in my original code, the menu is not a child of the main div. they are 2 different dives, the menu having a z-index of 500, and tweens into the screen when the user clicks a button. I thought the main div should not be able to catch events when it has another div ontop of it.. does'nt it?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Once it is dropped optop of the other div, it should not catch any events. if it does for some unknown reason... you might have to find a workaround. Add some javascript to that button click. should be easy and solve your problem. and don't worry about being difficult. it is no trouble

Comment: Ok, i found the problem! I only needed to give the big main div a height value. now i just toggle the overflow value between 'hiddnen' and 'scroll' using jQuary.
Thanks!

Comment: it is a big pleasure. and you contributed. You should post the answer to your question. it might help other people.